# Await returns [Function] instead of value

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

await returns [Function] instead of value

Trying to return the values of a query from firebase by making use of the async and await function. Results returned are either [Function] or Unhandled Promise Rejection Warnings. New to promises, async and await but I've tried the basic examples on a few websites, most having the resolve and reject parameters, which I assume should be the same as the firebase promises.

I tried 2 different version, both with incorrect results.

```
get_all_users:async function(){
   ref = db.ref("/user_data");
   const value = await ref.orderByKey().on("child_added", function(data){});
   console.log(value.val().name);
}
```

returns UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

```
function get_async_users(){
  ref = db.ref("/user_data");
  ref.orderByKey().on("child_added", function(data) {
    return data.val().name;
  });
}
```

returns undefined

Expected either one to return the names from the query.

Comment: Does the Firebase documentation say that `on` returns a promise? It seems like an unlikely thing to return, based on the function name...

Answer (score 1):

`on` is for listening to *all events that ever get triggered*. Therefore it does not return a Promise, as a Promise represents a single value being available, and as it does not return a Promise, you can't `await` it (or at least: it doesn't make sense to do so, its a no-op).

If you want to wait for the first occurence, there is [`once`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query.html#once), which also returns a promise that can be `await`ed.

Concerning the UnhandledPromiseRejection: You should always wrap your asynchronous code into a `try / catch` (inside an `async function`), or attach a `.catch` to the upmost promise in the chain, then you can handle those errors correctly.

Comment: thanks Jonas. Apologies that I wasn't really clear on what "on" and assumed it was a promise. I suspected it was a promise because the value returned was undefined and I had to "wait" for the result to appear.
the once does return the first occurrence but what if I want all the data from the query?

Comment: Then there are probably more appropriate methods in the Firebase documentation ....